# Is something as simple as $2+2=4$ a theorem?

Tags: logic, soft-question

I read in a math textbook that a statement as simple as $2+2=4$ is not really a theorem. The book didn't deny it was a true statement, just that it was not significant enough to be considered a theorem. But I think that book made a mistake. Just because it is simple and very easy to prove, does not mean it is not a theorem. But what is the truth of the matter?

Comment: They may be arguing that $2+2=4$ is a definition rather than the theorem. In some way we've created the notation to encode information related to the properties of numbers but it's still just notation.

Comment: In Whitehead and Russell's 1910 work [_Principia Mathematica_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principia_Mathematica), the proof of theorem number $\star 110\!\cdot\! 643$ is given; it states that $1+1=2$.  (In W&R's notation, this is written “$\vdash\, . 1+_{c}1=2$”.) They add a note that “the above proposition is occasionally useful”.

Comment: In the [axiomatic version of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) it is obviously a theorem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a formal definition of *Theorem* that logicians use which is just "something provable in the formal system you're using".

In this sense $2+2=4$ is a theorem the same way that $0=0$ is a theorem.

However, mathematicians usually distinguish between theorems, propositions, lemmas, corollaries, etc. And there's not a formal definition of any of these. And usually mathematicians reserve the word *Theorem* for "important" results, which is definitely ambiguous but hey, we make the rules.

In this sense $2+2=4$ is definitely (usually!) not a theorem.

Comment: Don’t you mean “‘something provable (without *assumptions*)….’”?

Comment: @PW_246 I don't know what your formal definition of assumption is in this case. I know logic isn't as standardized with notation as math is, but what I wrote is what I have always seen for the definition of theorem.

Comment: @Julián I think just removing "(without axioms)" would be much more accurate. Formal systems have axioms and the whole idea is to use them.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen sure! I can delete it if it's confusing. To me the idea was to have something analogous to a tautology but in the syntactic world.

Comment: @Julián "Tautology" and "provable without axioms" do correspond, roughly. Thing is, $2+2=4$ isn't tautological... it might be trivial, but its truth/proof depends on (nonlogical) axioms, not just the definitions. Like you need to know you can move the parentheses around in $(1+1)+(1+1) = 1+1+1+1.$ (I don't disagree with your post as written now though... and $2+2=4$ is certainly 'morally' closer to $0=0$ than, say, Lagrange's four square theorem, of course.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen you're right! I got carried away by considering $2+2=4$ a shorthand for $PA→ 2+2=4$ where $PA$ is the conjunction of the subset of the peano axioms necessary for the proof.

Comment: (To me this was implied otherwise how do you even talk about $2$ and $4$. You could have the signature for PA and not the axioms but that would be odd to have without stating explicitly.)

Answer (score 4):

> Is something as simple as $2+2=4$ a theorem?

It may be "common sense," but it must also be a theorem in axiomatic number theory. Consider Peano's Axioms that formally define the set of natural numbers $N$ in the language of set theory as follows:

1. $0\in N$
2. $\forall x\in N: \exists y\in N:y= S(x)$
3. $\forall x,y\in:N:[S(x)=S(y) \implies x=y]$
4. $\forall x\in N: S(x)\neq 0$
5. $\forall P\subset N:[0\in P~ \land ~\forall x\in P: S(x)\in P
       \implies P=N] $

While addition can simply be defined, hoping you get it right, the very existence of the usual addition function on $N$ is a **theorem** that can be formally proven using Peano's Axioms, set theory and basic logic. (The proof can be hundreds of lines long.)

If we use axiom (2), above, to define $1=S(0), ~2=S(1), ~3=S(2)$ and $4=S(3)$ then we can actually use that addition function to prove the **theorem**: $2+2=4$.

Why bother formally proving that which is "common sense?" Only to test your axioms. If you could not use them to derive commonsensical results like $1\neq 0$ or $2+2=4$, then something would be seriously wrong with them! When you design and build a new car, for example, the first "test" of that car might be to see if you can turn on the engine and drive a short distance that you could easily walk. If that simple test fails, something is wrong.

Comment: +1 for noting that "$2$" and  "$4$" are defined as names for numbers.